# How to deploy MERN project on Hostinger (web hosting)

Tags: node.js, deployment, hosting, mern

I am new to web development and I have a Developed MERN web application which I want to deploy on my hostinger (web hosting). I cannot find any tutorial which teaches deploying on web hosting. there are tutorials which teach to host on VPS. I don't have VPS. is VPS required for MERN application to be deployed? Can I deploy the project on only web hosting without VPS? if yes than please tell me the steps. Thank you

I haven't tried anything yet

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to deploy MERN stack to a hosting service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54854594/how-to-deploy-mern-stack-to-a-hosting-service)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65610618/1145388) talks about shared hosting services such as Hostinger.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.